# How to install MIRACL c++ library in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I'm trying to install the library from the link https://certivox.org/display/EXT/2.+Installation . But when I try the command:

```
gcc –I. –c –O2 mr*.c
```

I get error saying :

```
gcc: error: /I.: No such file or directory
gcc: error: –c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: –O2: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: @ElderGeek consider: that's `-I` not `-l`.

Comment: @ElderGeek go into the edit history, copy-paste the nonformatted code into the `gedit` text editor or the command line - it's `-I`, never was `-l`.  (Just tested, too.)

Comment: @ThomasW. the question was edited while I was making my comment.

Comment: There's a good example on how to use the -I switch here: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because that dash character is wrong. Look very carefully:

The command you're running:

```
gcc –I. –c –O2 mr*.c
```

What you really should run:

```
gcc -I. -c -O2 mr*.c
```

Look at the dashes. Can you see the difference?